# Correct Way to Calculate Uncertainty

Tags: homework-and-exercises, error-analysis, statistics

Given a function $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ of $n$ uncorrelated variables $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, each of which has some small absolute uncertainty $\Delta x_1,\Delta x_2,...,\Delta x_n$, I know that the absolute uncertainty in the value of $f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ can be calculated from the normal distribution by the following quadrature formula:
$$\Delta f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n\biggr(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\Delta x_i\biggr)^2}$$
Now consider the following function from kinematics giving the height of a projectile thrown upwards from the surface of Earth with an initial velocity $v_0$ after time $t$ has elapsed: $$h=v_0t-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$$
Assume that $g=9.8\text{ N}/\text{kg}$ has no uncertainty to it, and suppose $v_0=4.0\pm0.2\text{ m}/\text s$ while $t=0.60\pm 0.06\text{ s}$. Now the idea is to view $h=h(v_0,t)$. So applying the quadrature formula I mentioned early, the absolute uncertainty $\Delta h$ in the projectile's height $h$ should be:
$$\Delta h=\sqrt{t^2\Delta v_0^2+(v_0-2gt)^2\Delta t^2}=\sqrt{0.60^2\times0.2^2+(4.0-2\times9.8\times0.60)^2\times0.06^2}\text{ m}\approx 0.165\text{ m}\approx 0.2\text{ m}$$
On the other hand, one can first define two auxiliary functions $p(v_0,t)=v_0t$ and $q(t)=-\frac{1}{2}gt^2$. Applying the same formula, the uncertainties in these auxiliary functions are:
$$\Delta p=\sqrt{t^2\Delta v_0^2+v_0^2\Delta t^2}=\sqrt{0.60^2\times0.2^2+4^2\times0.06^2}\text{ m}\approx 0.268\text{ m}$$
$$\Delta q=gt\Delta t=9.8\times0.60\times0.06\approx 0.353\text{ m}$$
But clearly we can write $h=h(p,q)=p+q$ (and $p$ and $q$ are uncorrelated because $p$ depends on $v_0$ whereas $q$ doesn't). According to this then, it would seem that:
$$\Delta h=\sqrt{\Delta p^2+\Delta q^2}\approx\sqrt{0.268^2+0.353^2}\text{ m}\approx 0.443\text{ m}\approx 0.4\text{ m}$$
So clearly these two approaches yield distinct values $0.2\neq 0.4$ for the absolute uncertainty $\Delta h$ of $h$. Which one is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and p and q are uncorrelated because p depends on v0 whereas q doesn't

Here is your mistake. In fact, $p$ and $q$ have a very strong negative correlation of about $-0.89$. Including that negative correlation should reduce the propagated error in the 2nd case.

[image: Scatter plot of p vs q]

Comment: oh okay thanks! But then would you say that the first approach that got an uncertainty of $\Delta h =0.2\text{ m}$ is correct?

Comment: By the way, I personally think the first calculation that gave $\Delta h=0.2\text{ m}$ is correct, but I saw the second calculation method that gave $\Delta h=0.4\text{ m}$ in this Harvard University document from Fall 2007 (it's on page 3), so I became confused: https://www.dropbox.com/s/um3tyrt8gqrauvx/Error%20Propagation.pdf?dl=0

Comment: The document says that "practically speaking, this means that you have to write your equation so that the same variable does not appear more than once" (otherwise they would be correlated?). But I guess that's just not true?

Comment: @SurfaceIntegral whenever you are in doubt you can just do a Monte Carlo simulation, like what I did to show that p and q were correlated. When I did that I get that the standard deviation of $h$ is 0.163

Comment: Hmm...I suppose empirical evidence never hurts, but is there a more systematic/mathematical way to know if two variables are correlated or not? For instance, are $v_0$ and $t$ correlated (in the example I gave)? I wouldn't think so, but I'm not sure how I would prove it either.

Comment: @SurfaceIntegral as far as I know there is no general way to know. It has to be done empirically in general. There may be some special case theorems that apply to this scenario, but I don’t know them. I just go to Monte Carlo at the least difficulty because it is easy and it is very general. So I learn one easy general technique rather than memorizing a bunch of special case proofs